# Is it ok to store all types of values as image data type in sql?

Tags: sql, image, store

Is it ok to store data of different data types as a single universal data type, say 'image' in SQL? I will also store the data type value in another column and use this value inside my code to convert the data back into its proper type.
The advantage I get by doing this - I can avoid joining n number of tables.
Can some one point me to the down sides of storing data in this way?

Comment: you should instead try to learn how to use joining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty bad idea for several reasons:

- Query performance will be bad because the optimizer can't utilize indexes, foreign keys etc. because they don't exist.
- You don't get referential integrity and thus can make no assumption about your data.
- You introduce a new additional point of failure, because what if the data doesn't correspond to the specified data type?
- The person having to maintain the code after you will hate you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be ill-advised to take this approach for at least 2 reasons

1. You would, as you note, constantly be type casting on input and output.  I can't see this as a useful operation, though I can see it as a time-consuming one.
2. You would exchange the (modest) difficulties of joining N tables for the (much less modest) difficulty of making N joins on your one mother-of-all-tables.

And then there is the more philosophical argument, along the lines that you are proposing to use a multi-tool (SQL) as if it were a hammer.  Not every data type is always a nail.  You will be much more productive, and I would assert enjoy your work more, if you work with rather than against the nature of your tools.

And I agree with what Daniel Hilgarth has already written.

Comment: I thought type casting input and output in the code would be less time consuming than joins. Looks like it is not so then.

Comment: If your joins are time consuming, most likely there is something wrong with your database. Maybe there are no indexes on the foreign keys or the data types don't match and an implicit conversion happens. You could check the explain plan of your query to find out what takes so long.